# Adding namespace removes friend access to class private members

Tags: c++, class, namespaces, friend

I have a Vector class split into declaration (.h) and implementation (.cpp) files:

```
// a_vector.h
class Vector
    {
    private:
        float f[4];

    public: 
        ...
        // friend operator overloads
        friend Vector operator * (const float& s, const Vector& v);
        friend Vector operator * (const Vector& v, const float& s);
}
```

and

```
// a_vector.cpp
...
// friend operator overloads
Vector operator * (const float& s, const Vector& v)
{
    return Vector(s*v.f[0], s*v.f[1], s*v.f[2], s*v.f[3]);
}

Vector operator * (const Vector& v, const float& s)
{
    return s*v;
}
```

Now I'd like to add a namespace to my class. Following [Danny Kalev's Article](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=61), I made the following changes to the two above files:

```
// a_vector.h
namespace a
{
    class Vector
        {
        private:
            float f[4];

        public: 
            ...
            // friend operator overloads
            friend Vector operator * (const float& s, const Vector& v);
            friend Vector operator * (const Vector& v, const float& s);
    }
}
```

and

```
// a_vector.cpp
...
// friend operator overloads
a::Vector operator * (const float& s, const a::Vector& v)
{
    return a::Vector(s*v.f[0], s*v.f[1], s*v.f[2], s*v.f[3]);
}

a::Vector operator * (const a::Vector& v, const float& s)
{
    return s*v;
}
```

I now get a debugging error for the first definition of the * operator overload stating that " 'f' is a private member of 'a::Vector' ". I thought friend definitions have access to a class' private members? It works fine if I don't have the Vector class within a namespace. How does putting the Vector class in a namespace change how friends work?

**EDIT:**

Added answer below.

Comment: I have the same problem. Part of the solution is the fact that you declare a friend function a::operator* while in your cpp file you declare and define another function which is not in the a:: namespace. Hence, it is not the friend function you declared in the header file. Replacing operator* by a::operator* might fix it.

Comment: That seems to do the trick! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare a friend function a::operator* while in your cpp file you declare and define *another* function which is not in the a:: namespace. Hence, it is not the friend function you declared in the header file. Replacing operator* by a::operator* should fix it.